# Centering CSS elements in other CSS elements

Tags: html, css

Lets say we have a

```
<div id="1">
   <h1 id="2">Some Text</h1>
   <h1 id="3">Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

And well put these elements on a rectangle in CSS

```
#1{
   width:50%;
   heght:50%;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #ff4741 , #f8a2a1);
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

And then I want to center the 2 `<h></h>` in the exact center of my rectangle .-.
How can I do that so when I resize the page that thing will stay in the center of my rectangle ?

If I try to

```
#2{
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   left:50%
}
```

The text starts getting drawn from the middle of the page instead of the middle of my element , and if I do `left:25%;` which would be the middle of my element related to the page it would actually start to get drawn from the middle point to the right , not centered.

So how can I do it ?

This is the actuall code I curently have , My problem here is with the header , on diferent screen sizes the text on the header is not centered in its rectangle.

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    height: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #555;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top:20%;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.headref {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    text-align: justify;
}

.headelemet {
    position: relative;

}

.AccentLine {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    height: 2.5%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff4741;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #00A0C6;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}







#logo_show_off{
        position:absolute;
        left:0%;
        top:5.8%;
        height: 90%;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #ff4741 , #f8a2a1);
}

.logo{
    margin-top: 5%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 25%;
}

#mascotLogo{
    height:45%;
}

#MyLogo{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    right:60%;
    top:20%;
}

#MyMascot{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    left:60%;
    top:60%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Ionut.E portfolio</title>

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto|Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://www.1001fonts.com/home-planet-bb-font.html" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainLogo.css">

</head> 
<body>
 <div id="logo_show_off">
  <h1 id="MyLogo">THIS IS MY LOGO LOGO</h1>
  <img id = "mainLogo" class = "logo" src = "Images/Logo.png">
  <h1 id="MyMascot">THIS IS MY MASCOT LOGO</h1>
  <img id = "mascotLogo" class = "logo" src = "Images/mascot_logo_png.png">
 </div>
 
 <!––HEADER––>
 <div class="AccentLine"></div>
 <div id="header">
  <strong id="logo">IONUT.E</strong>
  <strong class="headref headelemet">
   <a href="index.html">Home </a>
  </strong>
  <strong class="headref headelemet">
   <a href="index.html">JavaScript </a>
  </strong>
  <strong class="headref headelemet">
   <a href="index.html">Graphic Design </a>
  </strong>
  <strong class="headref headelemet">
   <a href="index.html">Visual Design </a>
  </strong>
  <strong class="headref headelemet">
   <a href="index.html">Contact me </a>
  </strong>
 </div>
<!––HEADER––> 

 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>
 <h1>test</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you create fiddle plz

Comment: 1. Id can't start with number 2. div {text-align:center;} should work.

Comment: its a random Id I chose , it could be anything , I never putted numbers for id's so I never knew numbers wont work.

Comment: Rupesh I have created the fiddle u asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either center the `h1` block-level elements with `text-align: center` on the `.container` element or you can center the content inside the `h1` element by
using `text-align: center`.

```css
.container {
  height: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #ff4741 , #f8a2a1);
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Some Text</h1>
  <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, you can not use a css selector that starts with a number. That means `#1, #2, #3` are not valid selector. And solution to your issue is to add a line of css property `transform: translateX(-50%);` to your `<h>` element.

Answer (score 1):

To center elements I suggest using flexbox.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```